# Spring mapping issue with foreign key

Tags: java, spring

> Hello friends,
>
> Can someone help me figure this out, I am trying to pull the id value
>   from the Dept table and pass that value to the dept variable
>   in the Record class.
>   I tried to make the dept
>   variable of type Long but hibernate was throwing a fit about not being
>   able to set Long value. So instead, I followed this
>   ref([http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/01/17/jpa-one-one-mapping/][1])
>   thinking Spring was going to figure it out. Since it did not work out,
>   I figured I should reach out for help.

```
public class DataServiceImpl{
        public void dataRepo(String val) {
        Dept deptRepo = deptRepository.findByDeptName(val);
        dept.setDept(deptRepo.getDeptId());
        }
    }
```

> Database structure for table record

```
id  integer

dept_id integer(foreign key which references id field in dept table)
```

> Database structure for table dept

```
id (integer)
```

> Here are the entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Record implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dept_id")
    private Dept dept;

#Getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Dept implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long deptId;

#Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: I guess `private Department dept;` should be `private Dept dept;`

Comment: for ref: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: @Rcordoval, yes I updated it

Comment: in record's dept object your are setting long, you should set dept object instead.

Comment: @CODI checkmy answer, and let us know !

Comment: I made changes with your suggestion but it was still giving me issues so I completely removed the relationships and just used plain old programming logic and that worked. I would need to do some more research on relationships just for next time. Thanks for all your help